# React Router Dom: Why does <Link /> correctly navigates to desired path/page but doesn't update the scrollY position to the top of the new path/page?

Tags: html, reactjs, hyperlink, jsx, react-router-dom

I have a simple React application that has a **Home** and **Privacy Policy** page. When using `<Link />` from `react-router-dom` the current page scrollY position is maintained from path A to path B.

My home page has a footer at the bottom of the page. When I scroll to the bottom of the page and click on the Privacy Policy link it correctly takes me from the root path (`/`) to the new path of `/privacy` but I am not at the top of the privacy page when I get there. It maintains the scrollY position.

1. Why is this?
2. How should I be doing this to correctly navigate to the privacy policy and arrive at the top of the page?

I am importing like so: `import { Link } from "react-router-dom";`
My link looks like this: `<Link to="/privacy">Privacy Policy</Link>`

Comment: You need to implement "scroll to top" behavior yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `react-router-dom` doesn't do scroll restoration to my best knowledge.
2. Try using `useLayoutEffect`.

Import it from react and use the following inside your Privacy page. This will allow you use `window.scrollTo()`.

```
import { useLayoutEffect } from "react";

const Privacy = () => {
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, []);
  return <div>... your code</div>;
};

export default Privacy;
```